# 1998 Renault Clio screeching/squealing clutch

Tags: clutch, noise, renault

Ever since I got my Clio a few months ago it's been making a sort of squealing sound when I'm letting the clutch pedal out at a certain RPM. If I'm moving off at a lower RPM (such as for downhill starts or just flat starts) it will not make the noise. It also does not make the noise if I move off at a higher RPM (e.g. for uphill starts); it seems to be somewhere in the middle, between low and higher RPM. The clutch does not seem to be slipping or any signs of wearing other than this sound; the car moves off and engages every gear perfectly fine, it's just an annoyance more than anything. It's been an ongoing problem for months and I never bothered doing anything to it or checking it out as this is my first car and I'm not looking to put any/much money into repairs. Over the months the problem does not seem to have gotten any more severe or frequent than it was when I got it.
Any idea what this is? 
Also would the car pass UK MOT test with this noise? 
Thanks

Comment: My 2000 Clio does this also - has done for about a year.. it's annoying more than anything as now trying to sell and nobody is interested. It passed the MOT - was told it is not the clutch going, but to fix the noise would mean a whole new clutch. No idea what it is though I'm afraid but it should pass the MOT as mine did. If you find out what it is, please let me know and I've been searching and searching for an answer but nothing. Seems more people have the issue when they depress the clutch rather than release it. Grr, annoying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a bearing in the clutch. There's a fair bit of labour in pulling a clutch, even just to inspect it, so I'd recommend ignoring it until other symptoms appear. eg turn up the stereo!

Comment: Good point - the throwout bearing can do that. Next clutch job would be a good time to change it out.

Answer (score 1):

My bet is... the clutch disk (the friction part) happens to vibrate at a frequency that coincides with that particular engine RPM, and is barely free enough to vibrate with the clutch disengaged. If I'm correct, it's nothing to worry about - only an annoyance, and shouldn't shorten the life of the clutch.